# Router default undesired login page prompt

Tags: logging, netgear-router

This morning when I first came to my computer I noticed that my chrome browser had my Netgear Nighthawk X6S Tri-Band Mesh Extender network login page on it with the dialog "Session has timed out". I find this odd since I haven't been there lately.  Makes me worried that someone out there is on my machine.  But I want to prove it before I get to paranoid  I am looking for logs that would be on the Nighthawk X6S Tri-Band Mesh Extender as it would be easier to nail down the time of attempted access before I go looking at the windows activity logs(they are daunting to look at and I don't really know what I am looking for).  Documentation say nothing about logs of any kind, which is hard to believe.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: On the router go to Administration > Logs. If the Connections to the web-based interface of this router is checked then you should see the access time in the log. See [Netgear Nighthawk X6 R8000 Logs Router Screenshot - PortForward.com](http://screenshots.portforward.com/routers/Netgear/Nighthawk_X6_R8000/Logs.htm) for a screen shot.

Comment: Router administration is different than these mesh extenders provided by netgear.